# .htaccess map to port number of cherrypy app *silently*

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web-applications, cherrypy

Hi I am successfully remapping the standard port of a `www.my-domain.com` to the port where the web-app is running with the following rule (port 33333)

`RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}"   "!^www\.my-domain\.com" [NC]
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}"   "!^$"
RewriteCond "%{SERVER_PORT}" "!^33333$"
RewriteRule "^/?(.*)"         "http://www.my-domain.com:33333/$1" [L,NE]`

Of course now the port is visible in the web browser. How do I hide it? Note that I do not have either `mod_proxy` available on my server nor access to the `httpd.conf`.

Thanks

Comment: you can't. the only way to hide the port in a url is to use the DEFAULT port, 80 for http, 443 for https. ANY OTHER port **REQUIRES** the port to be specified in the url. Otherwise the browser will just hit the default. If you are proxying, then your 'public' url can be on port 80, and the proxy resends everything to your private port, but that has nothing to do with mod_rewrite

Comment: Without mod_proxy and using P flag or proxypass, you're out of luck. Marc is right and you can't hide non standard http ports. You have to listen on 80 and proxy it to your backend on port 33333

Comment: @Panama Jack, thanks for mentioning the P-flag. I put it there and it seems to work! It seems weird bcs the administrator told me that the mod_proxy is not available for my server... Is there a simple command line which lets me see if it actually activated or is that all already proof enough?

Comment: @dmeu they must not know what they're talking about. If the [P flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) works, mod_proxy is enabled. Not sure I'd mention it to them. :) However since you only have .htaccess, this is the only way you can proxy.